# error: parse error on input `::' in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am a newbie to Haskell and Iam trying to implement `Set` ADT with one function named  `union` using `Lists`.here below is the code :

```
import Data.List

data Set a = Set [a]
union' :: Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union' xs [] = xs
union' [] ys = ys
union' x:xs ys = | not $ x:xs `elem` ys = x:union' xs ys
                | otherwise union xs ys
```

I think am doing something terribly wrong here in type allocation. while compiling it's showing an error as below

```
error: parse error on input `::'
union' :: Set a  -> Set a -> Set a
```

pardon me for such silly mistakes but any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Your type declaration is for a function called `union'` (union prime), but your function is called `union` - it might not be related, but you might want to clean it up anyway.

Comment: [`notElem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:notElem) is a thing, btw.

Comment: This question isn't useful if you don't provide the full error message.

Comment: that was the complete error I got @melpomene. what else there to get more errors that was just 7 line code

Comment: @læran91 There should be at least a filename and a line number in there.

Comment: the file name saved as (set.hs).why do you need a line number here @melpomene ? as I showed the error did happen at union' :: Set a  -> Set a -> Set a

Comment: Instead of just copy/pasting the full error message, you've spent the past 20 minutes arguing with me. This leads me to believe you're trying to hide something, namely that either the error or the actual code don't match what you've posted here.

Comment: Lol why do I need to hide anything.I asked the question because am confused and I don't know where did I made a mistake.I didn't ask question to poke you or argue with you .anyway I apologise if you feel like that.if you know where did I made a mistake help me | otherwise "Thank you" @melpomene

Comment: OK, then I'm going to be explicit: I tried your code and it doesn't produce the error you claim it does. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know where your mistake is because you're withholding essential information (namely, filename and line number). Why are you making it hard for other people to help you? And why are you still dodging the question? "*Lol why do I need to hide anything.*" I don't know, but you still haven't posted the full error message yet.

Comment: okay brother. that was the complete code and that was the only error I getting & I don't know what did I do wrong I think my compiler has some problem I guess . and you felt dodged because you dodged me like " 
Instead of just copy/pasting the full error message, you've spent the past 20 minutes arguing with me" so that was the reply I can give for false claim(I didn't copy pasted anything here).

Comment: This error sounds like the way it is. parse error on input `::'.  I tried your code.  The error I got is at the part of "= |" "|". So maybe your error is about space indentation. So make sure everything is aligned and nested well.

Comment: And make sure you don't use tabs. Haskell indentation depends on space. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the original code for examining, I can only leave a version for you to compare and may you find something that cause parsing error on '::'.

```
import Data.List

data Set a = Set [a]
union' :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union' (Set xs) (Set []) = Set xs
union' (Set []) (Set ys) = Set ys
union' (Set (x:xs)) (Set ys)
 | not $ x `elem` ys = cons (Set [x]) (union' (Set xs) (Set ys))
 | otherwise = union' (Set xs) (Set ys)

cons (Set xs) (Set ys) = Set (xs ++ ys)

instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
  show (Set xs) = show xs
```

The following is what I bumped into when I started to modify the source code:

1. You don't need to put '=' before guard '|'
2. You need equal space indentation for guard '|'
3. missing '=' for the second guard expression.
4. called union instead of union'
5. you are gonna need your datatype constructor 'Set' for every pattern matching.
   (or a wrapper function for unpacking Set constructor and a helper function passing two list. In this way, you may not need to make your own cons. I just think of that.)
6. Cons for Set instead of (:)
7. And a show instance for Set in order to show the result of union'.

Just trust your compiler and everything will be fine eventually! Good luck!